# How can I make this div slide down from top with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have 2 divs children of a display block parent. I would like to make div #2 (green) be on top of div #1 (red). With "on top" I'm not talking about z-index, I'm talking about literally being on top of the other. And then I was wondering if there could be a way to make div #2 slideDown()

As far as I tested, jQuery slideDown() or slideUp() works differently. 
In the demo I made, when I run

```
$('.item-1').slideUp();
```

The item 2 is sliding up instead of item 1, why is that? I'm getting confused.

Any hints would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

```js
window.slide = function() {
 $('.item-1').slideUp();
}
```

```css
.items-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  display: block;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-alignment: middle;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.item-2 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="slide()">
Click me!
</button>

<div class="items-container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `slideUp()` routine is working correctly.  Because item 1 is sliding up, it causes item 2 to move up.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan done. You voted for close?

Comment: No, I did not vote to close.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan oh ok. I just updated the question with the fiddle there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` methods animate the height of the matched elements, not position as you seemed to want: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/.

What you seem to want is to `translate` the `div` it so that it moves on top of the first one.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

```js
window.slideUp = function() {
 $('.item-2').addClass('slideUp');
}

window.slideDown = function() {
 $('.item-2').removeClass('slideUp');
}
```

```css
.items-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  display: block;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-alignment: middle;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.item-2 {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform linear 1s;
  background-color: green;
}

.slideUp
{
  transform: translate(0,-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="slideUp()">
SlideUp!
</button>
<button onclick="slideDown()">
SlideDown!
</button>

<div class="items-container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So long as the element is `display: block` afaik. It can get dicey for inline elements though (I believe due to the ways browsers handle whitespace).

Comment: @msqar, I looked up the specs and one of the examples they use is using % too. Search for translate:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: Very old but still helped me for my plugin

Answer (score 1):

[`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) works by changing the height of the element. As that element gets shorter, following elements will move up the page.

As seen in the documentation:

> The `.slideUp()` method animates the height of the matched elements. This causes lower parts of the page to slide up, appearing to conceal the items.

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, item1 slides up as expected and as defined [by the doc](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) :

> Description: Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

So your div slides up and disappears, and item2 doesn't "move", just fills the space in the DOM after item1 has been hidden.

Comment: Oh got it. But what if i want item 2 to slideDown and hide item 1? Do i have to do it differently? maybe with css transitions and transforms?

Comment: or use .animate

Comment: Yea, i will do that then :/ i thought it could be possible with slideDown/Up of jQuery. Thanks.